# use current_user in ActionController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, controller

I want to override some methods of a controller(which inherits from ActionController) from a third party gem.
My problem is that I can't access current_user because the controller does not inherit from ApplicationController.
Is there any way accessing current_user inside this controller ?

**Edit:**

3rd party gem -> spree_api

in spree_api for every request we must provide an api_key,but I want to use some method that doesn't need any special permission an can be called by guest users. so I skip authentication for those methods like this:

```
module Spree
  module Api

    ProductsController.class_eval do
      skip_before_action :authenticate_user, :only => :index

      def index 
      ...
      current_user # -> undefined local variable or method `current_user'
      ....
      end
end
```

Comment: What's the 3rd party gem that you are using?

Comment: 3rd party gem : spree_api

Comment: And which controller are you using?? Help us to help you, by giving as much information as you can in order for us to identify and resolve your problem. 'A controller' in 'a gem' isn't helpful.

Comment: I want to use current_user in productsController, index action.

Comment: `ProductsController < BaseController < ActionContoller::Base`, which has `#current_api_user`

Comment: You can include `Devise::Controllers::Helpers` to get the `current_user` method from devise. However you should provide some more details (edit the question please!) on exactly what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @DavidK-J, current_api_user find user based on api_key which return nil if there is't any api_key

Comment: @max, I have tested your solution already, but didn't work :(
`undefined local variable or method current_user`

Comment: @saman you can add a method to User Model to return current_user and call method like `User.get_current_user`.

Answer (score 0):

To find current user controller needs to have something to identify user entity.
In case of API this something is api_key.
And in most other cases its a token sent in with request headers via browser which devise's current_user method reads and identifies user.

You can skip user authentication (api_key in request) where user is not needed like ProductsController etc. But you will surely need user (and hence api_key) in others like CheckoutController etc.